# How to launch Tor from the command line

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, browser, tor-browser

I downloaded the Tor Browser DEB file from the official website and installed it - it works fine when I search for it in the dash and click on the icon, but I use the terminal a lot and would like to know how to launch it from the terminal.  I've tried `tor-browser` and numerous variations of that with no success.  I can't find anything useful online.  I want to launch tor-browser from the terminal.  It is already downloaded and installed.  I do not want tor.

Comment: Okay I'll edit the question to clear up confusion - I didn't know that tor and tor-browser were different

Answer (score 1):

As @bodhi.zazen said in the comments, the `tor` command is working fine; it's just that Tor is *already* running. If you read the output from the `tor` command, you'll see that this is indeed the case.

This is similar to how you can't have to instances of Audacity running at the same time.

---

If the `tor` command were really not working, you'd get this output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ tor
The program 'tor' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Comment: question has been edited, please edit answer :)

Comment: @ChristianF97 - Please run this command for me and post the output: `ls /usr/share/applications | grep tor`

Comment: Not going to list all my applications for security reasons, but one of the items in the list is `tor-browser-en.desktop`

Comment: that's the only tor-related item

Comment: @ChristianF97 - Okay, please run this command then: `cat /usr/share/applications/tor-browser-en.desktop | grep Exec` (The part after `grep` is CaSe SeNsItIvE)

Comment: Thank you so much!  That put a file at `/usr/bin/tor-browser-en.sh` and I marked it as executable with `chmod` then I put a file at `/usr/local/bin/tor-browser` and wrote a bash script telling it to execute `tor-browser-en.sh`, just so the command is a bit cleaner.  Perhaps make this into a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the tor-browser is already installed, type in the following command to open the tor-browser through the command line in Linux:

torbrowser-launcher